# c++ only allow certain parameters to placed in argv[1]

Tags: c++, argv, argc

Im trying to write some code that will only let one of four letters be entered in the argv[1] parameter. if it is another character the letter q should come up.

so ive written

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

char D, A , R, B;

if(argv[1] != D||A||R||B)
{
  cout << "Q" << endl;
  return(0);
}
```

can anyone please help me

Comment: Have you considered reading an introductory book on C or C++?

Comment: Your code does not even have a `main()` function. As suggested, read some introductory material first.

Comment: this code is wrong in so many levels...

Answer (score 2):

This `if(argv[1] != D||A||R||B)`

is not proper syntax

`D`,`A`,`R`, and `B` have not been initialized to anything! They are what you call variables.

nor do you have a `main()` function. You are missing a lot here, but I will answer how to check for the right `char`.

you will probably be better served by a `switch statement`:

```
switch (*argv[1])
{
    case 'D':
    case 'A':
    case 'R':
    case 'B':
       cout << "Not Q" << endl;
       break;
    case 'Q':
       cout << "We have a Q" << endl;
       break;
    default: 
       cout << "unknown char" << endl;
       break;
}
```

There are a lot of other things we could get into here, such as how to properly structure a program, or general C/C++ questions, but this should get you at least started.

Comment: @phresnel: sorry `*argv[1]`.. or even strcmp.. but this question has a lot left for it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in C++. You have to

```
if (argv[1] != D && argv[1] != A && ...)
```

and generally it is better to check how many parameters there actually are (though `argv[0]` and `argv[1]` are always present).

Also, you lack a `main()` function and therefore not even have `char *argv[]` defined:

```
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
 ...
}
```

Comment: Not to mention that you cannot describe execution flow in global scope like that...

Comment: Downvote for ... what exactly? Oh yeah, in the internet, nobody knows you are a dog.

Comment: Heh, random downvoters are constantly passing by :)

Answer (score 0):

A third option would be in C++11:

```
#include <set>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
  if (argc < 2)
    return 1;

  // here is the actual check:
  if (std::set<char>{'D','A','R','B'}.insert(argv[1][0]).second) {
    std::cout << "Q" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "OK" << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

This uses a temporary set that holds all values and an initialisation list to put the desired values in the set. Then it tries to `insert` the passed value (i.e. `argv[1][0]`) into the set and checks whether it was successful in inserting the element (accessing `second`), then it wasn't it and is therefore "wrong".

Note that we do not have to check for `arvg[1][0]` because every array has at least one element located at position `0`.